# Should I open a new question or completely edit the original (from somebody else)?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

A user asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685822) and I spent quite some time to help him.

In the course of understanding the issue, I uncovered the underlying issue, which seems like a bug in Excel 2007/VBA - for which I unfortunately do not know a solution/workaround.
In addition, I also found a related problem that did not occur directly at the inquirer but only subsequent when we looked into the issue.

So my question is: what is the better approach here:

1. Significantly editing the original question - boiling down his code to the 4 main lines - and adding the other issue as well, or
2. Add a new, "clean" question that only shows the two items (but refers to the other question)

I did the latter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715989/conditional-formatting-of-overlapping-ranges-in-excel-2007-vba-bug), but not sure what's better...

Answer (score -2):

If you had the answer then you could add a new question and then answer it yourself because the question is likely to be substantially different to the original (even though the answer was the same). Then in the original you could point to your new question.

But because you don't currently have the answer you can help clarify the original question. You don't have to completely reword it, you can just add an edit at the bottom. The original text of the question could still be important, you should ensure the original symptom is clearly stated and any unrelated waffle from the OP (who didn't know better) is separated out or removed.

IOW, unless it is a great candidate for a self answered question, I would edit the original question into shape.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - will do so next time! It would still feel a bit like hijacking the OP's question - as I do not know the answer but instead widened the scope of the question... :-/